# Is there a function in Python to insert an element in a data structure with constraints

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data structure with a sorted array with k elements and a Minimum Heap with n - k elements.

I've already coded the Minimum Heap and a helper function to insert the element into the array.

Now I would like to code the part to insert an element either into the heap or use the helper function.

constraints for insertion of the new element as follows:

1. case:

- <[−1]:   insert into the sorted array -> use the helper function
- Insert  ′  into the heap using heap insert.

2. case:

- ≥[−1]: insert into the heap  .

```
# helper function
    def insert_array(self, elt):
        self.A.append(elt)
        j = len(self.A)-1
        while (j >= 1 and self.A[j] < self.A[j-1]):
            (self.A[j], self.A[j-1]) = (self.A[j-1], self.A[j])
            j = j -1 
        return


    def insert(self, elt):
        size = self.size()
        if size <= self.k:
            self.insert_array(elt)
            return 
        elif elt < self.A[ - 1 ]:
            self.insert_array(elt)
        else:   
            self.H.append(elt)
            self.bubble_up(len(self.H) - 1)
```

Comment: The built-in if-else conditions provide that functionality to you.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure I fully understand your question, you can do the following:

```
if j < A[k-1]:
    insert j into sorted array using helper function
else:
    insert j into heap using heap insert
```